# SugarCRM filter search result by custom field from current user account

Tags: sugarcrm

I have the custom field "country_id_c" in both "User" and "CustomModule", I need to limit the user to see only lines from his region (filtering it by country_id_c).
There are two search forms:

1. when you see the search result of CustomModule from menu
2. when you add CustomModule as a relationship to other module by using
   picker (pop up window).

I found how to filter the result in 1 case with hard-coded value:

file: custom/modules/CustomModule/metadata/SearchFields.php

```
$searchFields['CustomModule'] = array (
...
'country_id_c' =>
array (
  'query_type' => 'format',
  'operator' => '=',
  'value' => 'Argentina',
  'db_field'=>array('country_id_c',)
),
...
```

what I'm missing here is how to get the current logged-in user's country_id_c. And how to do the same for the (2) search form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value by adding:

```
globals $current_user;
$current_user->country_id_c
```

Comment: If that answers your question could you please give feedback?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work. Even after add `globals $current_user`, which is required to access this object, the `$current_user` doesn't contains the custom variable `$country_id_c` inside (probably need to load it in some way). Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure, sorry globals $current_user; is needed. Did you add the custom variable correctly to the vardefs? Please post your vardef for it then I try to reproduce the problem on my machine.

Comment: You are right, it works. It was named as country_c in this module, this why I couldn't find it first time. Could you please edit the answer and add there globals $current_user? And do you know how can I do the same for the relationship selector list?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: $this->bean->load_relationship('aRelationship');
        $relationships = $this->bean->aRelationship->get();

Comment: Never mind, apparently it works on all lists. Thank you for answer!